# How to test my app on iOS 8?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

I have Xcode 5.1 and I've received the code of an app developed for iOS7 (with this version of Xcode) which is said to be compatible with iOS8. I want to test the app in my iOS8 device but when I try to build the code I've received I have no choice to build with iOS8. Should I install Xcode 6 and build with iOS8? or should I build for iOS7 and install in my iOS8 device?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Build with Xcode 5 and iOS 7 then run on the iOS 8 device. If you use Xcode 6 and iOS 8 you open the need to do a lot of extra work (which needs to be done eventually but it could add weeks of work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Xcode 6, or 6.1 Beta. Xcode 5 is not for iOS 8 development.

EDIT: But you could always build it for iOS 7 and install it on an iOS 8 device, as you mentioned, as long as the app doesn't need any iOS 8-specific features.

Comment: But the question is about an iOS 7 app. Using Xcode 6 is not appropriate in this case unless the developer is prepared to go all in with iOS 8.

Comment: You can always change the Deployment Target to be iOS 7. I think there isn't too much reason to avoid Xcode 6, unless I am missing something?

Comment: The app was developed with a Base SDK of iOS 7. Changing that to a Base SDK of iOS 8 should be done at some point but it's not trivial. It all depends on the app and the developer's timeline.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Yes, assuming it's not time to switch over, there would be other considerations to make.